# how do i create a JS object with 2 keys

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to store values for string translation.

this works:

```
> var yourObject = {};
> 
> yourObject[yourKey] = "yourValue";
> 
> console.log(yourObject );
```

i would like to have 2 keys

```
yourObject[lang][key] = "yourValue";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the same approach for a single property and assign the object to another property.

```js
var key = 'cat'
    lang = 'en',
    temp = {},
    object = {},

temp[key] = 'Cat';
object[lang] = temp;
console.log(object);
```

Or use a direct approach with an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var object = { en: { cat: "Cat" } };

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have like this , this will work for you

```
var yourObject = {} ; 
var lang = "hi";
var key = "data";
yourObject[lang] =  {};
```

Then you do like this

```
yourObject[lang][key] = "data in other lang";
```

And can also access.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an object within an object:

```js
let yourObject = {
  "lang": {
    "key": "value"
  }
};

console.log(yourObject["lang"]["key"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a multidimensional array. Here is a one-liner:

```
yourObject[lang] = [{key: "yourValue"}];
```

Answer (score 1):

OR, you can use ES6 key interpolation like this

```
let result = {}, firstkey = 'firstkey', secondkey = 'secondkey';
result[firstkey]={[secondkey]:{somedata:'...'}};

result[firstkey][secondkey] will then give you {somedata:'...'}
```

simple,easy and fun. And you don't need another empty temporary object.